# Scrolling starts at the wrong offset on chrome but works fine on firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to add smooth scrolling to my website navigation but I'm having a tough time figuring out why the scrolling starts at the wrong offset first then moves correctly.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
        var scroll_start = window.scrollY;
        console.log(scroll_start);
        if (scroll_start > offset) {
           navToLight();
        } else {
           navToDark();
        }
});
```

this is how i handle click events on nav anchors:

```
 $('a.nav-link').on('click', function () {
     var target = $($(this).attr('href')).position().top;
     console.log("This is the target: "+target);
     $("html, body").animate({
         scrollTop: target
    }, 700);
});
```

this is what i get in the console when i try to navigate to the "about section" in the website.

[image: Figure 1]

[Website demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pzsfuu0b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser also scrolls for you, what you should do is stop propagation and preventDefault on the event:

```
$('a.nav-link').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   var target = $($(this).attr('href')).position().top;
   console.log("This is the target: "+target);
   $("html, body").animate({
     scrollTop: target
   }, 700);
});
```